# django Multiple newtwork request to api cause unique violation error

Tags: django, postgresql

So i have an API that takes a keyword and runs some logic, then inserts the data into Keyword table.
The keyword model is:

```
class Keyword(BaseModel):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    key_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return my_unicode(self.text)
```

Now due to some bug in my frontend js code a api request was getting sent two times on a button click(not a major issue). But in the backend during the processing of the keyword following code runs which was creating UniqueViolation error:

```
def get_data_for_keyword(key, region_id, language_id):
    # key is the keyword text that we need to save into db which is coming from network request
    # Some code

    keyword = Keyword.objects.filter(text__iexact=key)

    if keyword.exists():
        keyword = keyword[0]
        # some code

    else:
        keyword = Keyword(text=key)
        keyword.save()
        # some code
```

Scenario: Two request come with the same keyword(due to the js bug).
Expected behaviour: Both request check the existence of that keyword in DB, the one that runs first doesn't find it in DB creates it and the other one finds it in DB and further processing happens.
But whats happening is somehow both request are getting executed simultaneously and both when filtering are not finding that keyword and both are trying to make it and save it. One is getting successfull and other is getting

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_keyword_text_31586601_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (text)=(new api) already exists.
```

Is this the expected behaviour by django, My question is do we as application developer need to handle such cases or django should handle such cases.
I am using Postgres as DB.
Do let me know if stack trace is neccessary.